# How to mock nil object passed to a block in OCMock

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

To stub a the following method of the class *Network*

```
- (void)userLogin:(NSDictionary *)credentials
completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, id, NSError *))handler;
```

I create a mock like this:

```
id mock = OCMClassMock([Network class]);
```

I want to stub this method so the block gets called with arguments *YES*,*nil*,*nil*. How to stub the values for objects like *NSError* and *id* with *nil*?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
id mock = OCMClassMock([Network class]);

OCMStub([mock userLogin:[OCMArg any]
    completionErrorHandler:([OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:OCMOCK_VALUE(YES), [NSNull null],
                                    [NSNull null], nil])]);
```